# How to gitignore everything except hidden subdir?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm using this `.gitignore` file for excluding everything in the current dir and subdirs, except the `!` prefixed entries:

```
*
!.profile
!.vim/snippets
!.vimrc
```

The `.profile` and `.vimrc` files are showing up as untracked in `git status` but not the `.vim/snippets` directory. Any idea how to include this directory as well? I've tried `!.vim/snippets/` but it doesn't work either. Thanks

Comment: Is `.vim/snippets` already tracked? That would cause it to not show as untracked, but it wouldn't be ignored, either...

Comment: Ok, I think I've replicated a similar case. What seems to happen is the `*` entry matches `.vim`, so it doesn't look any further. Try adding a `!.vim` entry as well. It still doesn't show `.vim/snippets` in `git status`, but you can `git add` it without getting the "path is ignored" message. Other files under `.vim` still get ignored, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works OK. One can explicitly say what dirs and files that should be included along the path:

```
*
!.vim
!.vim/snippets
!.vim/snippets/*
!.profile
!.vimrc
```

So this would include the `.vim` dir and the `snippets` directory but only the files (`/*`) in the `snippets` dir.