# Trying to not ignore subfolders with files inside

Tags: git

I created this path `~/.vim/foo/bar/my_file` and in `.gitignore` i add this line:

```
!.vim/**/*
```

I expected when i did `~$ git status`, the `foo/` or `bar/` folder was added in the list of new stuff but no..

Folder `foo/` doesn't have anything except the `bar/` folder.

Here it is my `~/.gitignore` file:

```
*
!*/
!.vim/*
!.vim/**/*
```

Anyone knows how to not ignore `my_file`?

Comment: We might need to see the rest of `.gitignore` to understand what's happening...

Comment: Note: `**` doesn't have any special meaning in git. It's the same as just `*`.

Comment: @twalberg i added my .gitignore

Comment: The follow question may be what you want.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633974/how-to-gitignore-everything-except-hidden-subdir

Answer (score -1):

I am not seeing the problem here. You should not need to add anything to `.gitignore` as far as `my_file` goes.

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/Steven/.git/

$ mkdir -p .vim/foo/bar

$ touch .vim/foo/bar/my_file

$ git add .vim

$ git ls-files
.vim/foo/bar/my_file
```